# Page width(resizing for all device)

Tags: html, css, margin, pixel

i'm having issues with CSS for `width` and `margin`. I'm making a web page for all device(PC, smartphone and tablet), using HTML `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0" >`and Px(not auto or %) as unit for CSS.

By now, during window resizing(browser PC), elements still rest in their position(works page) but, on mobile(smartphone and tablet) it looks differents results:

[image: Tablet Views] [image: Smartphone Views]

Any comment or solution for that could be helpful, thanks.

**UPDATE CODE:** Page is built like this example https://jsfiddle.net/1wfr3vpq/ All classes property sets to "auto", were originally in px(example:`width:1024px;` or `margin-left:150px;`)

Comment: add some codes...

Comment: I'm not searching for code issue, it works as it must be. What you need to know is just in question.

Comment: probably that is happening because of some code issue,if you didn't post some code the answer will be opinion based

Comment: Check `css media queries`, and their ordering. That's the only answer we can give you.

Comment: I'm very basic on web but you ask the entire code for the page which is not helpful. As you could see I'm asking for the rules to apply on CSS for @media or others, problem start and end in the <meta> tag content or, at least, in CSS properties for body so i'm not update jsfiddle for that

Comment: @Ultrazz008 i used to apply the max/min `width` for page but, all elements loses their CSS properties and page won't works anymore so I'm searching a viewport solution for tablet cause Smartphone and PC views works fine in front of tablet view.

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 800px) { /* desktop */ .container { width: 100%; max-width: 600px; } }`  - example for css, for desktop max-width + width

Comment: Could you at least make issue somewhere on jsfiddle so we can see where's the problem, small code, small html & css which sets width..

Answer (score 0):

using media-query you can do this.
For example, you execute some CSS only for desktop computers using min-width

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) { /*The following CSS runs only for displays with a width (in pixels) of more than 800px*/
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { /*The following CSS runs only for displays with a width (in pixels) of less than 800px*/
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

Also, see this great link. https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/
with this you can get the idea